# Audit question is off-topic as defined, but audit suggests it should remain?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I came across this audit question in the "Low Quality" queue today:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4627988

The question is very clearly asking for offsite tools - or lacks a minimal understanding of the problem (no code written, no problems have been run into - just wants an example). Either way, it seems pretty clearly off-topic.

> Does anyone know of newer opensource components that work with .NET 4.5 & WPF or have examples on how I could build my own component?
>
> What I'd like to have is simply a radial progress bar or something on par with the battery gauges/meters in common battery apps in the Windows Phone store. From what I can tell, WPF/VS 2013 doesn't offer this kind of component out of the box. I know that Telerik and a few other 3rd parties offer something similar, but I'd prefer to use something open source or build it myself.

The policy seems pretty strict on [Asking for off-site tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I mean granted, there is [a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23047288/1450077) that I found when I looked further after failing, but the queue doesn't show that, and the queue is for a flagged question.

Any insight into why this came through as a fail?

Comment: Yup terrible audit. It's just because its so highly voted. You can probably help remove it from the audit set by casting a vote to close on it (though I'm not exactly sure if that'll do anything, a downvote is probably more effective). I'd have said if it's not a tool recommendation then it's certainly too broad.

Comment: I just failed an audit by closing [this off-topic Docker question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799282/resource-usage-by-stopped-docker-containers) in the LQ review queue (and got myself a 2 day audit ban since the same thing's happened before :-/) Annoying. But I closevoted it anyway, and hopefully others will as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>Copied from https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773</sub>

While there is no "officially implemented" solution to [bring a “human factor” into review audit composition / selection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168374/165773), one can use whatever means are at their disposal now in order to bring the "human factor" to audits selection.

When you spot a slippery audit, go straight to the "item" it uses and do the action *opposite to audit direction*.

- <sup>If you feel something rotten before submitting the audit, use link to the audit item to get there for corrective action. If you found that you were screwed after the audit, bad audit and item can be found in the [activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/recent-activity/info) in *reviews* subsection.</sup>

If the audit item has been wrongly served as "known good", down / close vote it. If it was pretending to be "known bad" against your judgement, vote it up / reopen.

I always do this to audits I disagree with.

---

<sub>As I typically open the items in queue in separate tab (for more thorough review), it often happens that I spot slippery audit and perform "correction" even before completing review. It feels somewhat weird to click *Looks Good* at the item you just downvoted but oh well. I am not going to decrease my "audit weight" just because of a [mistake in automatic selection algorithm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196949/request-for-review-close-reopen-known-good-audits) and knowing that reviewers after me won't get into this trouble anymore makes it less painful.</sub>